# Svn commit failed but didn't fail

Tags: linux, svn, repository

Alright so here's my problem. I have an svn server I setup on my site. I have it setup so that only authorized people can read/write it. So I can successfully checkout my repository, and whenever I make changes I get an error that says "svn attempt to write readonly database", but it commits.

Basically it commits, says it failed, but the revision goes through. Any ideas on how to fix that?
The server is linux based if that helps.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04
Using the newest TortusSVN and VisualSVN to connect.
I used apt-get to get the latest subversion
I use Apache2 with DavSVN

Here is my Apache config stuff

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName svn.MyServer.com
 <Location />
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /home/svn
     SVNListParentPath On
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "SVN Repository"
     AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/pass.passwd
     Require valid_user
     AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/subversion/authfile
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Alright, here is my /etc/subversion/authfile file

```
[/]
svn=rw
drilus=rw
d0c=rw
*=
```

In my specific svn repository I have this in my svnserve.conf

```
[general]
anon-access=none
auth-access = write
```

Alright so I feel dumb, while going through and finding all this information to clarify, I decided to do a recursive chmod of 777 on my specific repository, and that fixed the problem. 
The groups were right, and the users were right, I just figured when you used svnadmin to create the repository it would assign the right permissions.

Comment: Need more information.  What protocol are you committing over?  If over an http server, what are the log messages?  What are the file permissions.  What verion of svn is on the server/client, etc.

Comment: You might as well make that an answer, since it inspired me to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more information. What protocol are you committing over? If over an http server, what are the log messages? What are the file permissions. What verion of svn is on the server/client, etc.

Comment: I think it's just that your webserver needs write access to the repo data (doesn't necessarily need to be 777).